# Make whole document/body unclickable

Tags: jquery, html, css

On some of my AJAX requests I'm showing a loader, which dims the whole screen to show that the user shouldn't be clicking while it's loading. But... I haven't implemented anything to actually make the page unclickable.

My code has this structure:

```
$("#loading-overlay").toggle();

//my ajax

$("#loading-overlay").toggle();
```

So, when toggling the overlay, I also want to set a css class to my document, probably my `body` or `viewport`, that makes it completely unclickable. I've been checking around online but most solutions seems to take care of smaller sections and are bigger functions, or are outdated. How do I go about solving this problem?

Comment: all good but your 2nd toggle should be added to the ajax's onComplete callback.

Comment: Doesn't the overlay accomplish exactly what you're describing?  If you have an element covering the entire page, and that element has no click handler, then the user won't be able to click on anything.  (Or, more accurately, nothing will respond to the user's clicks.)  What isn't working here?

Comment: one solution should be have a div fixed that take all screen (position absolute, top bottom right left at 0) and a big z-index

Comment: If your over lay cover your bosy then page wont be clickable,

Comment: try using Jquery dialog with spinner

Comment: jQuery UI modal dialog

Comment: You could use `body.loading { pointer-events: none; }`, all modern browsers support it (no IE though, but thats seems like a fair cut-off for nice features).

Answer (score 3):

To prevent any click you can use [**`pointer-events: none`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events):

> The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events
>   may target its descendant elements if those descendants have
>   pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse
>   events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as
>   appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event
>   capture/bubble phases.

`pointer-events: none` is [widely supported by all main browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events%3A%20none), also IE 11.

```js
function showAlert() {
  alert("Alert");
}
```

```css
body {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showAlert()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've described doesn't really make that much sense, you've said you've dimmed the whole page with an overlay element but you want the page to be unclickable.

But if you've used an element that covers the whole page and it has a z-index high enough for the overlay effect to work then how are clicks firing when they should just be firing on the overlay element not those underneath?

Regardless of what I just said which seems a bit odd, you could use:

```
body {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The overlay covering the whole page will prevent real clicks.

Without forgetting the fact that the user could easily remove the overlay from the DOM, if he really wanted to click.

If you also wanted to prevent the user tabbing and submitting form with enter, you'll have to check on the form submission itself.  And on all other actions...

The most easy option is to just prevent any new ajax from being sent. To achieve this, you should have a global variable that keeps track of wheter an ajax call is going or not. You can use $.ajaxStart and $.ajaxEnd. Also in ajaxSend you can prevent the new request to go, if one is already being done... Like so

```
var ajaxing = false;
$.ajaxSend(function(e, xhr) {
    if(ajaxing){
        xhr.abort();
    }
});
$.ajaxStart(function(e, xhr) {
    ajaxing = true;
});
$.ajaxEnd(function(e, xhr) {
    ajaxing  = false;
});
```

You could add options to be able to mark some requests as blocking, and some not. Even your overlay could directly trigger in those event handlers.

Comment: does not really answer the question

Answer (score 0):

You should add the JQuery [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) method.

This will detect the click on the upper div and prevent further actions.

```js
$("#superdiv").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("<body>")
    .append("default " + event.type + " prevented")
    .appendTo("#log");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>event.preventDefault demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="superdiv" style="position: absolute; top:0; left: 0; bottom:0; right: 0; z-index:10; background-color:rgba(20,20,20,0.5)"></div>
  <a href="http://jquery.com">default click action is prevented</a>
  <div id="log"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A full width and full height overlay will do

```css
div#loading-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="loading-overlay"></div>
  <a href="#">Button</a>
</body>
```

Comment: `pointer-events:none` on the whole body is what OP needs, not an overlay with dark background, which is set on a `div` (for some reason)